# SharePoint list view formatting: Display grouped header next to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Is it possible to create a view (using json  sp schema) so the grouped header will display next to another? I've scanned  view sample and column samples (including board) but can't seems to figure this out

sample image using [custom-header view sample](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/custom-header)

From this view:

[image]

To this view:

[image: TargetViewenter code here]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using PnP Modern Search web part instead of using SharePoint Online JSON for View Formatting.

Specifically, picked Adaptive Card layout option and used Microsoft Graph/Search option for data source and this layout was possible.